# Ink filepicker android native sdk and policies

Tags: android, filepicker.io

I am trying to use the inkfilepicker native android sdk with an account that uses policies.
So when the sdk calls the filepicker backend to upload the file a 400 is returned, probably becuase I dont send an policy.
It looks like policies are not supported in the native sdk.
I cannot find any reference in the documentation about this.
Does anybody know how to use policies with the android sdk?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to Register for an API key and then set it in your code via,

```
FilePickerAPI.setKey(MY_API_KEY);
```

I recommend you to read this: [Ink File Picker Android Documentation](https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/android/)

Comment: Yes that is what I already know and do.  But we use behind my api key is an account we also use for the site and it uses policy files.     See [https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/security/](https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/security/). And sending policies and their signatures doesnt seem to be supported with the native sdk.